# David walsh's flip css resulting in vertical and horizontal space after flip element?

Tags: css

[jsfiddle of the problem with the space of the flip](http://jsfiddle.net/3Kup3/1/)

this is code from [david walsh's blog](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

There is a space between the two elements, even though no margin or padding seem to be specified. Someone got a clue where this space is coming from?
It is visible in two places

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="flipcardscontainer">
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front" style="background: red 0 0 no-repeat">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            This is ’ title2        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front" style="background: red 0 0 no-repeat">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            This is ’ post title 1        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* simple */
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;

    -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
*/

/* START: Accommodating for IE */
.flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* END: Accommodating for IE */

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background: lightgreen;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    background: lightblue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.front .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
    display: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00304a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.flipcardscontainer{
    width: 520px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This comes from `display: inline-block`.  If you want no gap, you'll need to use `float: left` or something from here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: It's a white space character - try http://jsfiddle.net/3Kup3/2/

Comment: does not seem to explain the height distance though?!

Comment: Set `vertical-align:top` on `.flip-container` to remove the height at the bottom.

Comment: When you place elements inline, any text is considered part of the box model for the purposes of spacing. It might not be completely intuitive, but white space in your document can impact what the browser regards as the "line" for purposes of determining the layout. Those tabs and newlines you use to indent and organize the markup form an implicit text node, which is being treated as part of the line that the divs are inline with. If you simply removed the whitespace from your markup between the two "cards", the space disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/A2eMG/

Comment: Vertical distance comes from the baseline vertical alignment of inline level elements (like text or inline-blocks). When inline-blocks have no statically/relatively positioned text content (or their `overflow` is not `visible`), their baseline becomes their bottom margin edge (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align). Just change `vertical-align` to anything other than `baseline`.

Comment: someone of you  wants to give the answer using vertical-align: top and removing the whitespace character? i don't like answering my own questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* simple */
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;

    -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
*/

/* START: Accommodating for IE */
.flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* END: Accommodating for IE */

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background: lightgreen;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    background: lightblue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.front .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
    display: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00304a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.flipcardscontainer{
    width: 520px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

try this

```
<div class="flipcardscontainer">
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front" style="background: red 0 0 no-repeat">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            This is lukas’ title2        </div>
    </div>
</div><div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front" style="background: red 0 0 no-repeat">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            This is lukas’ post title 1        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

this is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/UwShL/

http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/5jMnE/1/ <--- new fiddle without any line

Comment: border: 0px solid #ccc; <--- change this if you want to remove the line in between

Comment: both solutions have the problem that they are overlapping the blue areal. A combination of the 3 comments to my question yields the result

Comment: i not sure what you looking for . does this solve the problems?.. http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/5jMnE/1/ <--- did my answer wrong?

Comment: no. look at the bottom of the blue and red. They red overlaps blue at the bottom

Comment: suppose it already fix.. maybe i not save .. just change to this : margin-bottom:-7px; to margin-bottom:-5px;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/9EpZz/ <--- this is latest one.. forgot to save earlier in fiddle